# Class constructor within Photoshop

Tags: javascript, constructor, es6-class, photoshop-script

This should be straight-forward - creating a simple class within ECMA

```
class Sandwich
{
  constructor(filling)
  {
    this.sandwichname = filling;
  }
}
mysandwich = new Sandwich("Peanut Butter");
```

Photoshop says Error 9: Illegal used of reserved word 'class' line 1.

Only I'm sure there is a way to create class - just not with this type of construction, if you pardon the pun.

Comment: Does Photoshop support ES6? Because it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Photoshop supports only up to ES3.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this version of javascript. However, it is possible to emulate the functionality like so:

```js
function Sandwich(filling) {
  this.filling = filling;
}

Sandwich.prototype.someMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.filling);
};

var jelly = new Sandwich("jelly");

jelly.someMethod();
```

Comment: That works! Abeit with alert instead of console.log ;) I thought it might be the case, but i dismissed it as a function not a class d'oh!